# Keep code readable while using Prettier printWidth

Tags: javascript, prettier

I have code like

```
   public constructor(options: {
        attr: Logger,
        url: string,
        someNumber: number,
        type: string,
    }) {
```

When using printWidth from Prettier (for example     "printWidth": 140), it converts it to

```
public constructor(options: { attr: Logger; url: string; someNumber: number; type: string }) {
```

Which is understandable from the rule, but it makes it much less readable.

Is there some way to handle these cases where breaking to a new line would improve readability? Other than using *prettier-ignore*

I dont want to decrease the printWidth in general, because in other instances such values does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Prettier being "opinionated" as it is, it can be a pain to make it behave the way you want.

You can force it to wrap by inserting a line comment

```
public constructor(options: {
  //
  attr: Logger
  url: string
  someNumber: number
  type: string
}) {}

// or 

public constructor(
  //
  options: {
    attr: string
    url: string
    someNumber: number
    type: string
  }
) {}
```

or make it skip formatting the whole function with `// prettier-ignore`

```
// prettier-ignore
public constructor(options: {
  attr: Logger
  url: string
  someNumber: number
  type: string
}) {}
```

In this case, I'd actually recommend defining the type outside the class

```
type Opts = {
  attr: Logger
  url: string
  someNumber: number
  type: string
}
// ...
class YourClass {
  public constructor(options: Opts) { }
}
```